# Google Chrome installed on Ubuntu but missing from MATE Menu

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, google-chrome, software-center, mate

After installing Google Chrome on Ubuntu MATE, I can't search for it on the MATE Menu.

It is, however, found in Software Management. Now I have to launch it from there.

How may I make Menu recognize it ?

@K7aay: I don't seem to be able to right click on Applications as you mentioned. Did I miss something ?

The Applications sign is not clickable, neither the grey empty space. The only context menu I have is of each application itself.

[image]

Accordingly to my Google search, `/usr/share/applications` is another location that controls this menu. Strangely, I am seeing Google Chrome there but it's not on the Menu.

Comment: Updated answer below with two other methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

METHOD A: In the MATE Menu, right click "Applications > Edit Menus" then you will be able to edit the main menu.

METHOD B: Should that fail, open the Manin Menu applet, select the submenu you wish it to be in, then click the [New Item] button at upper left of the menu, and select the app you wish to add from the list of all the apps at left.

[image: MATE Main Menu addition]

METHOD C: If you find the GUI menu editor clunky the other way would be to edit the background desktop files directly. Copy an entry for an app which should be similar to yours from `/usr/share/applications` to `~/.local/share/applications`.

Rename that app's entry to match your new app.

Open it with a text editor with a right click.

Change the Name, Icon, Categories as required, and save it